# How to get the Decimal (REAL) number Only in an string in using an Excel formula or VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Help Needed: How to get the Decimal (REAL) number Only in an string in using an Excel formula or VBA?
I have in "column A" a string with just one decimal number on it. I want to extract that decimal (REAL) number ONLY but it is extracting the first number on the string. See below for details...

Current Situation:

I am using on Column B the Formula:

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,--LEFT(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, $A1&"1023456789")),999),ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))))

Column A                                                        |  Column B
"Some text"... The Value of Project 456 is 12.56 ... more text. | 456
Some Text"... Project 459 value is 13.5 ... "more text"         | 459
```

Desired Situation:

I want to get the decimal (REAL) number ONLY out of the string and ignore the numbers that doesn't contain decimals from Column A. Example:

```
Column A                                                        |  Column B
"Some text"... The Value of Project 456 is 12.56 ... more text. | 12.56
Some Text"... Project 459 value is 13.5 ... "more text"         | 13.5
```

Any help needed is appreciated, could be an excel formula or VBA solution.

Thank you!

Comment: somthing like ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UDF pasted into a standard public module code sheet.

```
Function realNum(str As String, _
                  Optional ndx As Integer = 1)
    Dim tmp As String
    Static rgx As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    realNum = 0

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,9}\.[0-9]{1,9}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            realNum = CDbl(.Execute(str)(ndx - 1))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Note that while it defaults to the first occurrence (e.g. B2), you can apply an optional parameter to get the second, third, etc. (e.g. B3).

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. Is there a reason to use your regex over what I was thinking of  ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)  ?

Comment: No, I use non-eloquent patterns as I simply don't use them enough to remember all of the shortcuts. Yours addresses the multi-digits without explicitly stating them.

Comment: I don't use often either so thought I was missing a trap somewhere. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This Array formula will sum all the number that have `.` in them, per stirng.  If only one per string then it returns just that one:

```
=SUM(IF((ISNUMBER(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$25)*99-98,99)))) * (ISNUMBER(FIND(".",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$25)*99-98,99))))),--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($1:$25)*99-98,99))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode:

[image]